# PHP Inserir imagem no banco Mysql Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, imagem, xampp

Estou tentando inserir uma imagem no banco `MySql` via `PHP`, na verdade o caminho dela, após mover a figura para uma pasta na raiz. Estou usando xampp.
Todos os códigos que testei insere normalmente os outros dados do formulário mas não a imagem. Alguém sabe de algo a mais que deve ser feito?
O que desejo é cadastrar um usuário e sua foto de perfil.
Podem ajudar?

Parte do Meu código(arquivos separados):

**Formulário**

```
<form method="POST" action="cadusuario.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                                      
    <label for="nomecompleto">Nome completo:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nomecompleto" id="nomecompleto" placeholder="Digite seu usuario ex. nome.sobrenome" size="50" />
    <br class="block" />
    <label for="nome">Usuario:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Digite seu usuario ex. nome.sobrenome" size="50" />
    <br class="block" />
    <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
    <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="Digite seu CPF"  size="45" />
    <br class="block" />
    <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
    <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha de acesso" size="30" />
    <input type="text" name="setor" id="setor"/>
    <br class="block" />
    <label for="avatar">Avatar:</label>
    <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" placeholder="Abrir Foto" />

    <button type="btn" data-icon="plus" data-rel="dialog">Cadastrar</button><p>                                 
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$nome  =   mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nome']);
$cpf   =  (int) $_POST['cpf'];
$senha =  md5($_POST['senha']);
$nomecompleto = $_POST['nomecompleto']; 
$setor = $_POST['setor'];
$PASTA = "./imagensPHP/";

$imagem = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
$temp = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];                      

if (!file_exists($PASTA)){
    mkdir("$PASTA", 0700);
}
move_uploaded_file($temp,$PASTA.$imagem);                       
$str_insert = "INSERT INTO `tb_usuarios` (cpf, nomeusuario, senha, nomecompleto, avatar, setor) 
                VALUES ('".$cpf."','".$nome."','".$senha."','".$nomecompleto."','".$imagem."','".$setor."')";                           
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$str_insert);          
print_r($_FILES['avatar']);
```

Comment: Você não está conseguindo inserir o caminho no banco, é isso? Você pergunta o que deve ser feito mas não esclarece o problema que está enfrentando, sugiro que edite a pergunta para que fique mais claro o ponto onde devemos ajudar

Comment: Você não deixou uma pergunta, mas vou deixar umas dicas: A) Você deveria verificar se os dados enviados no formulário estão no formato correto, por exemplo, em (int) $_POST['cpf'], resultaria em erro caso o cliente colocasse caracteres não inteiros. B) Sobre a imagem que é upada no servidor, eu vi em um vídeo sobre técnicas de segurança, que seria recomendado você re-salvar a imagem, ao invés de move-la pra uma pasta do servidor, pois podem subir uma imagem com código malicioso e espalhar para cada cliente que visualizar a imagem, e é interessantíssimo isso no seu caso, tendo em vista que você

Comment: Ao cadastrar o usuario, quero inserir uma foto de perfil. eu li que salvar o aquivo em uma pasta e seu endereço no banco de dados é melhor do que salvar a imagem diretamente no banco. nome, cpf... esses são cadastrados normalmente, mas a foto, não é movida para pasta e nem é salvo o caminho no banco.

Answer (score 0):

Na variable imagem, use:

`$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));`

Comment: A função `addslashes` não serve exatamente para o que você está imaginando. A função correta para escapar strings especificamente para inserção no DB em questão é `mysqli_real_escape_string`. - Além disso, `file_get_contents` não faz sentido no código do autor. Ele está guardando o arquivo no filesystem com `move_uploaded_file` e gravando o nome e o caminho, e não o conteúdo do arquivo no DB

Comment: Estou verificando e postarei o resultado, obrigado.